# Crossword solution I’m having difficulty in understanding

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Oddly dismissing Carnegie Hall’s backer and investor. (5)

Please explain how this cryptic clue works.

This clue is from [The Guardian Weekly, 5th January 2018](https://www.pressreader.com/uk/the-guardian-weekly/20180105/282248075943138).

Answer (score 18):

"Oddly dismissing Carnegie" = remove odd-numbered letters from the word "Carnegie" = _A_N_G_E.

Hall's backer = last letter of "Hall" = L.

ANGEL is a [type of investor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_investor).

Comment: Ugh. I was close, but looking at odd letters in "dismissing" and last letters in "Carnegie Hall".